# How to disable inf in gfortran?

Tags: gfortran

Using gfortran, is there a compiler option to not use inf?  Currently, a divide by zero returns an inf result.  I would prefer a run-time error, as was typical with legacy compilers.

My default compiler command is:

gfortran -fno-automatic -std=legacy -g -O0 -c

Comment: Try `-ffpe-trap=zero`

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but I still get x/0=inf instead of a run-time error.  I am running under gdb, could that be masking the problem?  After your suggestion, I check the docs, and -ffpe-trap=zero should catch it "on most systems"  I'm using windows 8 if that matters.